# How to pass custom parameters for a binding datatype inside a xml view?

Tags: sapui5

I have a custom datatype derived from sap.ui.model.SimpleType, which does some unit converting and number formatting. When I create an instance of the data type, it represents a physical power with a particular unit (W, kW, MW, ...) and I would like to specify that unit inside the constructor. If I work with JS Views, this is not a problem, because I can simply add an additional parameter to the constructor. But I don't know how to specify this parameter within a XML view. Right now I abuse the formatOptions from sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.PropertyBindingInfo and just pass the unit as an additional property. However, I'm afraid that this is not really best practice and also not optimal, since I am passing the formatOptions to NumberFormat.getFloatinstance(...).

Is there a way to implement my intention more elegantly? I am grateful for any advice!

Datatype definition:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/model/SimpleType",
  "sap/ui/core/format/NumberFormat"
], function (SimpleType, NumberFormat) {
    "use strict";
    
    return SimpleType.extend("myNamespace.model.type.Power", {
        
        aUnits : Object.freeze({
            "SI" : 1.0,
            "mW" : 0.001,
            "W" : 1.0,          
            "kW" : 1000.0,
            "MW" : 1000000.0
        }),
    
        constructor: function(oFormatOptions, oConstraints) {           
            let oDefaultFormatOptions = {
                    decimals : 0,
                    emptyString : null,
                    unit : "SI"
            };              
            
            oFormatOptions = Object.assign(oDefaultFormatOptions, oFormatOptions);
            
            SimpleType.apply(this, [oFormatOptions, oConstraints]); 
            this.oNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getFloatInstance(oFormatOptions);
        },
        
        formatValue: function(oValue) {
            if(oValue !== undefined) {
                if(this.oFormatOptions.unit !== "SI") {
                    oValue = this.convertValue(oValue, "SI", this.oFormatOptions.unit);
                }               
                oValue = this.oNumberFormat.format(oValue);
            }           
            return oValue;
        },
        
        parseValue: function(oValue) {
            oValue = this.oNumberFormat.parse(oValue);
            if(this.oFormatOptions.unit !== "SI") {
                oValue = this.convertValue(oValue, this.oFormatOptions.unit, "SI");
            }           
            return oValue;
        },
        
        validateValue: function(oValue) {
            return oValue;
        },
        
        convertValue: function(oValue, sSourceUnit, sTargetUnit) {          
            
            if(!this.aUnits[sSourceUnit]) {
                throw new Error("The source unit \"" + sSourceUnit + "\" is not valid or not yet implemented!" )
            }
            
            if(!this.aUnits[sTargetUnit]) {
                throw new Error("The target unit \"" + sTargetUnit + "\" is not valid or not yet implemented!" )
            }
            
            if(oValue) {
                oValue = oValue * this.aUnits[sSourceUnit] / this.aUnits[sTargetUnit];
            }
            
            return oValue;
        }
    });
```

XML View:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    controllerName="myNamespace.controller.MainView"
    core:require="{Power : 'myNamespace/model/type/Power'}">

    <Input id="InputA" value="{
                            path : 'model>powerA', 
                            type : 'Power', 
                            formatOptions : {
                                decimals : 0, 
                                emptyString : null,
                                unit : "kW"
                            }}" />
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: You could do it similar to a [Currency](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.type.Currency) or [Unit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.type.Unit). Either you pass multiple `parts` when binding your value or `powerA` should be a tuple containing the value and the unit.

Comment: @Marc I had a look into the documentation, but the usage of CompositeType is not completly clear to me. At it first glance, it looks like the Currency and Unit type also extend the formatOptions with new properties (e.g. source, similar to unit in my example). Passing the unit as a part of the value binding seems a bit suboptimal to me, because i only want to have the actual measure inside the control. Do you have an working example for this? Thank you very much for your efforts!